# How to make the entire row of react material ui datagrid clickable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I need my DataGRid row to be clickable, cause I need to enter details by clicking it,
so how to achieve that?

```
const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 20 },
  { field: 'startdate', headerName: 'Start Date', width: 150, type: 'date', editable: true },
  { field: 'enddate', headerName: 'End Date', width: 150, type: 'date', editable: true },
  { field: 'status', headerName: 'Status', width: 150, editable: true },
  { field: 'tenantId', headerName: 'TennatID', type: 'number', width: 110, editable: true },
];

const DataTable = (props) => {

  const styles=useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.root} >
        <DataGrid
          rows={props.rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={props.numberOfRows}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[props.numberOfRows]}
          checkboxSelection
          disableSelectionOnClick
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: What you mean by "i need to enter details" ? You need the cells to be editable ?

Comment: I need to make my DataGrid rows clickable so I can apply click events, for the moment I switched to using Tables instead of DataGrid

Answer (score 4):

Heres' the reference:
https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/

Use the prop `onRowClick`